# Generating Long Reports With PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to query a database (which contains hundreds of thousands of rows) several times and display the results in table format. The actual results involve tons of numbers. Displaying them in a web page doesn't work because it takes way too long to execute the script and the web page "expires" or times-out before it gets sent to the browser. Any ideas? Maybe I should have the results emailed? I'm not sure how to go about that.

Comment: take a look at the [`set_time_limit`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php) function...

Comment: Look into setting max_execution_time, memory limit for the script. You can also use _output flushing_. Another method is to load the results in an iframe so that the page doesn't look _blocked_ and user sees incremental output (using output flushing)

Comment: How about creating a summary table, populating it with the result of your slow running query (in a scheduled/background task) and query the summary table in your web page?

Comment: Besides set_time_limit, you also need to increase the web server timeout. Apache, Nginx, IIS all have `timeout` directive.

Comment: I think you need to define your problem better. Are there optimizations to be made on the database side (better structure, indexes, queries or more database server memory)?  Summarizing data to match your report structure is another option. On the php side you can try to control the timeouts, but results may vary based on the browser.

Answer (score 0):

I think the better explanation will be depend on what purpose you're trying to do and what is your main goal exactly.

You can use the var_export

> http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php

Or perhaps you can export the result to excel documents which can be done precisely like what you need, like graphics and whatsoever.

So you may choose many options to solve that, since you haven't decided the option you want to do I can't help with the code but if you want to cache the result you can give a shot by that.